# How to schedule Quartz Scheduler jobs for Ondemand trigger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, ondemand

> *I dont want to schedule as OneTime job or Cron job.*
>
> I want to trigger it with Rest API, whenever I want
>
> So far, didn't find any such Options.

Note: I have created custom Spring Quartz APIs for invoking Quartz jobs.

Comment: Don't you see contradiction between terms `schedule` and `on demand`? Why is it important for you to invoke something as a Quartz job? I'd extract functionality into some service and invoke it both via Quartz job (when schedule) and REST API (when on demand)

Comment: thanks Nikolai. I want all rest api call to trigger as jobs to maintain jobs history. I dont want as a separate api call.

Answer (score 2):

Quartz scheduler is a scheduling library that can run outside of web contexts and as such it does not provide any REST API. It provides a decent JMX and RMI APIs though that you can use to "manually" trigger your jobs as you wish.

Comment: I will write my Custom Rest APIs to call Quartz jobs.

Comment: OK, then you will want to explore this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-manage-quartz-remotely